# User's bcc-to-salesforce address via SOQL or API?

Tags: user-management

Is there a way to access, query, or update the following User preferences via the API or SOQL?

- The User's bcc-to-salesforce address

I've looked for any reference to these in the Force.com IDE's Schema Browser, and also checked the [API reference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm), but can't find any mention of them.

Thanks!

**NOTE:** I've split this question in two; leaving the first piece, which is answered here, and re-asking the second piece in [a separate question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1009/users-dashboard-assignment-via-api-or-soql)

Comment: I'd recommend splitting this into two questions since the answer for the first part isn't the same as the second. (Although I don't have an answer for the second one!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The email to salesforce addresses can be found in the [EmailServicesAddress object](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_emailservicesaddress.htm#topic-title)

```
Select LocalPart, EmailDomainName From EmailServicesAddress Where Function.FunctionName = 'EmailToSalesforce'
```

Comment: Amazing!  I had no idea that object even existed.  Any ideas about my other query?  I could also accept this answer and split that out as a different question.

Comment: Sorry, no ideas on the second part.